# date diff across months different

Tags: sql-server

Is there a way to do datediff by month that would show the total correctly? Below is two short compared to if I do an entire range. If I add +1 to each it makes the total 62 which is one over. Thanks.

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(day, '2019/07/13', '2019/07/31') AS DateDiff = 18
SELECT DATEDIFF(day, '2019/08/01', '2019/08/31') AS DateDiff = 30
SELECT DATEDIFF(day, '2019/09/01', '2019/09/12') AS DateDiff = 11
                                                             = 59

SELECT DATEDIFF(day, '2019/07/13', '2019/09/12') AS DateDiff = 61
```

Comment: Because your math is wrong. The difference for the entire period includes the first day of the 2nd and 3rd periods - which your first logic ignores.

Comment: How do I correct it?

Comment: How does anyone know which one is "correct" for you? Without knowing your goal, it is risky to make a suggestion. What is the source of your data? Did you chop the longer period into monthly periods? Are you perhaps moving down a path to writing your own interest calculation routines?

Comment: If someone was admitted 16 or more days in a month is what I'm looking for. It is across the range in the data so I have to separate it by months.

Comment: Well, now that you have edited your question, your "adjustment" logic is wrong. Notice that I said you need to account for the first day in the 2nd and 3rd periods to make the math match. You add 1 day for EVERY period which is incorrect and results in a difference of 1 in the other direction.

Comment: But rather than guess, post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that everyone knows what your actual data looks like and what your expected results are.

Comment: That is what the data looks like Admit date = 7/13/19 and discharge date = 9/12/19